# Mysq сортировка с группировкой

Tags: php, mysql

Есть запрос

```
SELECT
  star_user.id AS id,
  star_user.last_name AS last_name,
  star_user.first_name AS first_name,
  star_user.username AS username,
  star_user.email AS email,
  star_user.dtb AS dtb,
  star_user.sex AS sex,
  star_user.flg_expert AS flg_expert,
  star_user.flg_reg AS flg_reg,
  star_user.uid AS uid,
  star_user.dt_reg AS dt_reg,
  star_user.flg_new AS flg_new,
  profile.userpic AS userpic,
  profile.country_live AS country_live,
  profile.site AS site,
  profile.town_live AS town_live,
  star_user.flg_show_ru AS flg_show_ru,
  v_event_count.eid AS eid,
  v_user_follower.fid AS fid
FROM star_user
  INNER JOIN profile
    ON star_user.id = profile.user_id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN v_user_follower
    ON v_user_follower.user_id = star_user.id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN v_event_count
    ON v_event_count.user_id = star_user.id
```

Я его оформляю в представление (view) view_test
и потом в этом представление сортирую
select *from view_test order by eid
или
select *from view_test order by fid

но сортировка не работает, построение записей не меняется, в чем может быть дело?

Comment: приведите пример исходных данных и результатов сортировки. ну или только результатов.

Comment: Результатов нет, запрос же не выполняется.
Я проиестировал этот запрос в phpmyadmin? он срабатывает на ура. 
А на сайте я использую этот класс SafeMySQL
вот он полсе выполнения возвращает пустую строку вместо архива. Вот как я обращаюсь к нему
$sql="select *from v_user_profile where flg_reg=1 and id in($user_ids) $sort limit 0,$limit";
$result=$cls_db->query($sql);

Comment: ну дак чего вы это все не написали в вопросе то? Выведите, что там у вас получается в `$sql`, ошибка какая нить  в синтаксисе вот и не возвращает ничего

Comment: Да я на это не сразу обратил внимание.
Ошибки нет ни какой и возвращает пустую строку, вроде как отработал но записи не найдены, а запрос и структра я писал в начале:
select *from view_test order by eid или select *from view_test order by fid

Comment: вы чего приводите разные запросы то? тo про `view_test` пишите, то про `v_user_profile`. Если у вас запрос работает в пхпмайадмин, и не работает в пхп, значит вы его не корректно вызываете там. Но код вызова вы не приводите. Телепатов здесь нет, никто ответа с такой постановкой вопроса вам не даст.

Comment: Это один и тот же запрос просто я на view_test тесты делаю.
он описан в верху. И код я давал:
 $sql="select *from vew_test where flg_reg=1 and id in($user_ids) $sort limit 0,$limit"; $result=$cls_db->query($sql);

Comment: $user_ids - это пользователи через запятую
к примеру так 1,2,3, получаем такой запрос :

select *from vew_test where flg_reg=1 and id in(1,2,3)  order by eid limit 0,50

вызов:
$result=$cls_db->query($sql);

Comment: если вы копируете этот запрос в пхпмайадмин, то он выполняется там?

Comment: да, запрос выполняется